# Complete 2 textfields automatically by selection of one dropdownlist

Tags: yii

hello my name is claudia am new to this community my English is not very good my diculpas in advance, I'm doing a small project for a thesis and I am a beginner in yii and need your help, I have seen many tutorials dependent DropDownList, but I need to complete several dependent texfields 1 dropdown and I can not make it work.

I have two tables: program and partediario
program
id
game
article
drawing
variant

partediario
id
id_programa (heading-dropdownlist)
article
drawing
variant
meters

I need that when you create (_form) an item appears on a dropdownlist for which you select an item and textfields of article, drawing, variant, autocompleten automatically with program table data and then the data is saved.
I can attach appreciate some basic example.

thanks sooooo

Answer (score 0):

In `MyajaxController`:

```
public function actionGetDropDownInfo(){
    $selected_drop_down_val = $_POST['ddl']; // the drop down list's changed value 
    $article = "..."; // what you have to process with corresponding to $selected_drop_down_val 
    $drawing = "..."; // what you have to process with corresponding to $selected_drop_down_val 
    $variant = "..."; // what you have to process with corresponding to $selected_drop_down_val 

    echo json_encode(array(
        'article' => $article,
        'drawing' => $drawing,
        'variant' => $variant
    ));
    Yii::app()->end();

}
```

In your form, add a little of jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
         $('#drop_down_list_id').on('change', function (e) {
            //var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
            var selectedValue = this.value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('Myajax/GetDropDownInfo')?>",
                data: {ddl: selectedValue}, //post a selected value of drop down list
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function () {$('.loading-icon').show();},
                complete: function () {$('.loading-icon').hide();},
                success: function (data) {
                    // bind returned data into your fields
                    $('#article-field-id').val(data['article']);
                    $('#drawing-field-id').val(data['drawing']);
                    $('#variant-field-id').val(data['variant']);
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

Above is one of ideas how to achieve your point. I think your question was not much related to Yii, if you search by tag `form`, `jQuery` or `ajax`, you can find the other solutions that has been proposed.